# nginx ssl setup servernotfound and error.log file empty

Tags: ssl, nginx, digital-ocean, odoo-10

it's my nginx ssl configuration file, it seems everything normal but while trying to open url getting error servernotfound and log files are empty.

```
## myapp backend ##
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

## https site##
server {
    listen      443 default;
    server_name myapp.xyz;
    root        /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index       index.html index.htm;

    # log files
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/myapp.error.log;

    # ssl files
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp_xyz.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myapp_xyz.key;
    keepalive_timeout   60;

    # limit ciphers
    ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
    ssl_protocols           SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # proxy buffers
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    ## default location ##
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://myapp;
        # force timeouts if the backend dies
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # set headers
        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    # cache some static data in memory for 60mins
    location ~* /web/static/ {
        proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        proxy_buffering on;
                expires 864000;
                proxy_pass http://myapp;
            }
        }

        ## http redirects to https ##
        server {
            listen      80;
            server_name myapp.xyz;

            # Strict Transport Security
            add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
            rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        }
```

while i'm running `nginx -t`: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
no other services running in 80 port except nginx

> netstat -tulpn | grep :80 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8069
>   0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1533/python      tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>   2481/nginx -g daemo